# Problem in saving the value of an object key

Tags: javascript, class

Modify insert and remove to only work if the safe is opened, if the safe is closed then return Please open the safe first.

So all of my test cases are working properly, however I want to be able to do the following:
after removing an element via the remove method I want to access the element size value first
save it, then remove that element so that I can give the removed size back to the safe.

I tried doing it myself but I dunno how to code it, any suggestions?

```
class Safe {
  constructor(safeSize, passcode) {
    this.storage = [];
    this.safeSize = safeSize;
    this.oldSafeSize = this.safeSize;
    this.passcode = passcode; // <---- Modify Safe to have a passcode attribute
    this.isOpen = this.isOpen; //  <---- Add isOpen attribute to the Safe Class                     
  }

  insert(name, size) {
    //add restriction for insert to only work if this.isopen == true
    if (this.isOpen == true) {
      if (this.safeSize - size >= 0) {
        this.safeSize -= size;
        this.storage.push({
          name,
          size
        }); // push it as an object
        return true + " still accepting";
      }
      return false + " size limit reached";
    } //end of isOpen tesecase
    return "Please open the safe first"
  }

  remove(test) {
    if (this.isOpen == true) {
      let shouldSkip = false;
      let message = "";
      this.storage = this.storage.filter(element => {
        if (element.name == test && !shouldSkip) {
          //   let temporarySize= this.safeSize;
          shouldSkip = true;
          this.storage.pop(element);
          //adding the size back to the main safe only after
          //deleting an element
          //   this.safeSize = this.oldSafeSize - temporarySize;
          message = "The item " + element.name + " Has been removed"
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
      if (!shouldSkip) message = test + " Item not found";
      return message;
    }
    return "Please open the safe first"
  }
  setPassCode(passWord) {
    if (this.passcode == undefined) {
      this.passcode = passWord;
      return "Passcode has been set"
    }
    return "please reset passcode first" // todo make a reset password function

  }

  resetPassCode(providedPasscode) {
    if (this.passcode == undefined) {
      return "Set a passcode first"
    }
    if (providedPasscode == this.passcode) {
      this.passcode = undefined
      return "Passcode has been reset"
    }
    return "Wrong passcode" // or this.passcode != providedPasscode


  }
  openSafe(testCode) {
    if (this.passcode == testCode) {
      this.isOpen = true
      return "The safe is open and ready to use"
    }
    return "Wrong safe passcode"
  }

  closeSafe() {
    this.Open = false;
    return "The safe is closed"
  }
} // end of class

const safe = new Safe(10);
```

testcases:

```
safe.setPassCode("8642"); // => "Passcode has been set"

safe.insert("laptop", 8); // => "Please open the safe first"
safe.remove("laptop"); // => "Please open the safe first"

safe.openSafe("7531"); // => "Wrong passcode"
safe.openSafe("8642"); // => "The safe is open and ready to use"

safe.insert("watermelon", 7); // => true
safe.remove("watermelon"); // => {name: "watermelon", "size: 7"}

safe.closeSafe(); // => "The safe is closed"
safe.insert("watermelon", 7); // => "Please open the safe first"
```

Comment: During removal method, get the element size and then add it to the current safe size.

Comment: I dont understand how to do this via classes, can you show me an example please?

Comment: You've already done a similar job in insert method by subtracting the size of the element from the safe size. So add the element size in this way in removal method **this.safeSize += element.size;**

Comment: Dear lord I wrote it as this.size += element.size; and was getting NAN :D
Cooding is fun <3  Thanks alot, at least I see where my typo is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found one typo.

```
closeSafe() {
  // this.Open = false;
  this.isOpen = false;
  return "The safe is closed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  remove(test) {
    if (this.isOpen == true) {
      let shouldSkip = false;
      let message = "";
      this.storage = this.storage.filter(element => {
        if (element.name == test && !shouldSkip) {
          this.safeSize += element.size; // you've done similar job in insert method
          shouldSkip = true;
          this.storage.pop(element);
          //adding the size back to the main safe only after
          //deleting an element
          //   this.safeSize = this.oldSafeSize - temporarySize;
          message = "The item " + element.name + " Has been removed"
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
      if (!shouldSkip) message = test + " Item not found";
      return message;
    }
    return "Please open the safe first"
  }
```

Get the element size and subtract it from the safeSize.